# CRM : Workflow : Modify hidden field

Tags: xml, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

**How to modify hidden field of an entity e.g. ModifiedOn** (of an Opportunity entity) **with standart workflow** process?

The problem is that in the 'Set Properties' windows of workflow I can't see this fields.

I tried to do this in database, 'WorkflowBase' table, 'Xaml' column, modifying xml string there; but that language is kind of diffficult to understand.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
<mxswa:Workflow>
    <Sequence DisplayName="UpdateStep1">
        <Assign x:TypeArguments="mxs:Entity" To="[CreatedEntities('related_objectid#opportunity#Temp')]" Value="[New Entity('opportunity')]" />
        <Assign x:TypeArguments="s:Guid" To="[CreatedEntities('related_objectid#opportunity#Temp').Id]" Value="[InputEntities('related_objectid#opportunity').Id]" />
        <mxswa:UpdateEntity DisplayName="UpdateStep1" Entity="[CreatedEntities('related_objectid#opportunity#Temp')]" EntityName="opportunity" />
        <Assign x:TypeArguments="mxs:Entity" To="[InputEntities('related_objectid#opportunity')]" Value="[CreatedEntities('related_objectid#opportunity#Temp')]" />
        <Persist />
    </Sequence>
</mxswa:Workflow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a field to show up in the workflow designer update entity form, it needs to be part of at least one entity form, so if you do not see a field, it is probably not added to any of the forms on the entity.

Edit a form and add the field you want to show up on the workflow designer form, publish your customizations and when you reopen your workflow designer you should see the field.

Side note, some attributes like modifiedon, ownerid cannot be updated using either workflows or using SDK, CRM ignores such updates.

Comment: And there's no any way to modify this fields, either  with XML or sql query?

Comment: "modifiedon" field in particular or any field in general? If any field in particular, you would have to write a custom workflow activity and call the activity as a step in your workflow, which would be like re-inventing the wheel. If you are talking about "modifiedon" field in particular I am afraid not.

Comment: particularily this field.
In the fact, I've got a CRM system and I need to tune it up properly.
Now my endeavor is to understand and sort out all the customizations that was made before. And some of them appear to be very strange customizations.
So, if I can't change 'modifiedon' using standart Workflow, the best choice is to turn it off.

Comment: As a result, I found that this workflow is working, so (it is set to Note creation event) when I create a Note in any Opportunity, then this workflow starts and updates 'ModifiedOn' field. Dunno how it's done: directly modifying the value, or modifying something then saving opportunity, so ModifiedOn will change.